# One view per taxonomy vocabulary without a contrib module?

Tags: 8

What do I need to set in a D8 view, to have one view per taxonomy vocabulary without any contrib module?

Comment: Here is a gist of standalone custom code for achieving this:https://gist.github.com/markfullmer/3292ad93792d9530cacb7da5c42d1b21 . This is based on the more generic Taxonomy Views Integrator module.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 already uses the (now-builtin) Views for listing pages of content belonging to a certain taxonomy term.

That's a single view for all taxonomy terms:

[image: Taxonomy term view]

You can edit the view and make necessary changes you need
http://example.com/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term

Comment: Yes, but I want 1 views page setup per taxonomy vocabulary. So I can set different fields etc.

Comment: Well, by default that view uses the content row style with `Teaser` view mode, instead of `fields`. So if you add different fields to each vocabulary as desired, and update the `Teaser` view-mode with needed fields, you should be able to accomplish what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why anyone would have a "without a contrib module" requirement.

You can either do this with Page Manager, or you can write a custom module that alters the route and then dynamically calls a different view. Drupal 8 doesn't provide a feature to do this without additional modules/code

Comment: By the way I have found this project which was created to solve the purpose: https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi. But I have uninstalled it, since it seemed not to ready (errors). The route altering seems like a doable approach.